# Generate ul with jquery each and xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, list, each

I'm trying to populate a ul with <li> elements for each "row" tag inside of my XML document. Right now I just want it to display an arbitrary text until I can figure out why this is not even working, then I'll work on adding actual values from the file. #results is the <ul>.

```js
function getXML () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "garbage.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: generateList
       });    
};
function generateList (xml) {
    $(xml).find('Row').each(function() {
       $('#results').append(
       '<li class="results__item">1</li>'
       );
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getXML();
});
```

Here's a sample of the xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="yes"?><!-- Generated by abcexcel-->  
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Row
      A="TITLE"
      B="ALT_WORDS"
      C="DESC_ID"
      D="DESCRIPTION"
    />
  </Record>
```

All it does is repeat more records.

Comment: is it all right the function `generateList` is called without parameter?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik I took out the brackets after "generateList" and still to no avail. I've managed to do an ajax call before without passing any parameters, performing something similar.

Comment: Show sample of xml. Add an error handler also to see if that fires. Can get a lot more detail by inspecting actual request in browser dev tools network

Comment: @charlietfl I added a snippet of the XML.

Comment: Your code [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AuSRZmIDDqQ6ffN0wYsH?p=preview) when remove `()` . Need to inspect actual request for more clues .. status, expected response data etc

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, I added the fail clause to my ajax request, and I am getting the oops message. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with inspecting requests for clues, but this at least helps a little bit.

Comment: F12 opens dev tools...then look for request in network and click on it to inspect it. My guess is your path is wrong. Try to open the url it shows in another browser tab. but will see 404 status if not found on server

Comment: Also..are you opening this page on a server? localhost or otherwise?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using Xampp localhost. Upon inspecting the network, all my files give a 304 result. One interesting thing I did notice, though, is that my xml file is actually being shown as "xhr".

Comment: that's a type of request meaning `XmlHttpRequest` .. aka ajax. Any errors in the console of dev tools? Also can log the `err`  argument in fail and see what it shows you... `console.log(err)`

Comment: @charlietfl There used to be a 404 error when I used "../garbage.xml" for the file path, but since I changed it to "garbage.xml" there's nothing. I originally had my javascript file inside of a scripts folder and the xml file in the parent folder, so I figured I would have to navigate out one step first. Since then I just put the javascript and the xml in the same folder.

Comment: @charlietfl I logged the error and got the following object with a 200 status. Looks like it isn't getting it properly? Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standa…e make arrangem"
↵    />
↵  </Record>
↵</Records>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: What browser? might be not liking the xml structure or something like that. Note that what you posted was missing a closing tag also which I manually added in demo. There are more arguments of `fail` that you can use also ... see docs

Comment: It was errors in the xml file itself. I had generated this xml file from an ods file, and it was adding some bizarre entities. Thank you very much for your patience and help!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the getXML function:

```
function getXML () {
    $.get("garbage.xml", function(data) {
        generateList(data);
    });
}
```

or to use the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "garbage.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) { 
       generateList(xml);
   });
```

Comment: Why would this help...it's nothing more than a shortcut for `$.ajax` and you left out dataType argument

Comment: the function generateList() is called without the expected xml parameter, in this answer it is called with a parameter

Comment: no...when OP removes the braces to invoke function it is a reference to function and will work just fine

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately, and neither did removing the braces, although I think this is a step in the right direction. I feel like it's a really silly mistake that's just slipping by...

Comment: `success:generateList` will do exactly the same thing as seen in demo link above. So would `$.get("garbage.xml",generateList,'xml')`